# Caching data in ASPNET MVC SinglePageApplication

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, session, single-page-application

I´m looking for a solution or best practice concerning my problem. Since it is more an architecture-challenge I have got no sourcecode...

My problem is how I can deal with the ASP.NET session concerning my requirements. Or does it not fulfill my requirements?

Situation: I`m having a SinglePageApplication build on the top of ASP.NET MVC. The MVC-app provides the server-side interface to deal with the backend. The MVC-app calls services of a a different backend-server to request data. This data could be a lot and should be cached in the MVC-app.

As far as I see the ASP.NET-session does not seem to be the best solution for SPAs since its concurrent behaviour... ?! It is not possible to have concurrent ajax-requests if there is any request which requries write-access to the session (and that happens in my case since data has to be cached).

Example: Typical situation, at least in my application, is that when a user accesses a certain screen some ajax-requests are performed. E.g. the first request triggers loading data from the backend-server and takes some time (maybe about 30seconds...). It also requires write-access to the session since it should cache the data for this(!) user. Other requests now have to wait even though they only require read-access to the session and do not deal with the data to load. The behaviour that one request waits for another one should only happen in certain situations.

I could now implement a different mechanism to cache data for each user maybe using *System.Runtime.Caching* but is this the recommended or best solution?

What would be the best pattern to deal with that situation?

Are there any best practices?

**Edit2:**

One big point is the behaviour of the session when performing concurrent ajax-calls. I have prepared a small example: An application performing ajax-calls - some are using the session as ReadOnly - other ones are requiring ReadWrite. The actions have a timeout the issue more visible...

These are my controllers:

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
public class SessionReadOnlyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Perform()
    {
        Session["x"] = 5;

        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required)]
public class SessionReadWriteController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Perform()
    {
        Session["x"] = 5;

        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

This is the javascript-code which performs the ajax-calls. All calls are performed immediately:

```
jQuery(function ()
{
    $('body').append('<p>start....1</p>');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/SessionReadWrite/Perform?id=1',
        success: function () { $('body').append('<p>success1</p>'); }
    });

    $('body').append('<p>start....2</p>');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/SessionReadWrite/Perform?id=2',
        success: function () { $('body').append('<p>success2</p>'); }
    });

    $('body').append('<p>start....3</p>');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/SessionReadOnly/Perform?id=3',
        success: function () { $('body').append('<p>success3</p>'); }
    });

    $('body').append('<p>start....4</p>');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/SessionReadOnly/Perform?id=4',
        success: function () { $('body').append('<p>success4</p>'); }
    });

    $('body').append('<p>start....5</p>');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/SessionReadOnly/Perform?id=5',
        success: function () { $('body').append('<p>success5</p>'); }
    });
});
```

The results in my case (taken from the developer-tool of the internet-explorer):

- Call 1 responds after 1,51s
- Call 2 responds after 3,03s
- Call 3 responds after 4,56s
- Call 4 responds after 4,56s
- Call 5 responds after 4,56s

As I understand the behaviour of the situation the ReadWrite-Session-actions locking the session even for ReadOnly-Session-actions...?! (Or did I made something totally wrong?)

From msdn ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx ), last chapter:

> [...] However, if two concurrent requests are made for the same session (by using the same SessionID value), the first request gets exclusive access to the session information. The second request executes only after the first request is finished. [...] However, read-only requests for session data might still have to wait for a lock set by a read-write request for session data to clear.

Concerning my situation: If I want to cache data (in-memory is okay because the application is used by just a few users) in a SinglePageApplication I need a different concept than the session... therefore my question, are there best practices?

*Edit: Improved description of situation...*

*Edit2: Added an example...*

Comment: If you don't show some code or explain in a better way what you're doing, noone will help you. The problem can not be understood.

Comment: I hope description is better...

Comment: Now the description is perfect. You must do some custom coding. I've explained how you can do it with pseudocode. Making a full working sample is too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, finally, the problem is clear. As ASP.NET locks session access for the same user from different threads, Session will not allow you to solve your problem.

So, you need to implement something thread-safe by yourself. As you say in your question that there is no many people, and memory consumption is not a problem you can use an custom static class, whose lifetime spans from its creation (first access) to the end or the application (for example a server restart, or an app pool recycling).

You must decide if the data is stored for a user or for a session. If it's stored for a user, it will "survive" session timeouts. If it's stored for a session, identified by the session ID, you can handle the session end event in `global.asax` when the session ends.

You need two levels of locking:

1. one to access the data and locks for a particular user (or to create a new one and return it).
2. other for the user's lock and data (which is the described above)

For 1 you can use something like a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx). In this dictionary, keep the user id + the related lock and data for the user. Whenever you need to read or write data for a user, get it from this dictionary. This first level or lock warranties that the lock and data for a user is accessed without interference from other threads. You can use `GetOrAdd`method for this.

For 2, you can use an object with members like this, which will be the object returned from the dictionary when the user id is provided:

```
private object _data; // to store the cached data

public void StoreData(object data)
{
    // - If there is a lock return inmediately: 
    //   someone is already writing the data
    // - If there is no lock, create the lock, store the data in _data, 
    //   and release the lock
}

public object GetData(int userId)
{
    // - Wait for the lock
    // - Return data from _data
}
```

There are many ways to lock the access to `_data`. I'd use event wait handles: [see here for a full explanation](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Signaling_with_Event_Wait_Handles). But there are many more valid options.

With this implementation,

- any thread trying to read or write will get the user data from the dictionary 1. This lock, for `GetOrAdd` will be extremely short. The first that access the dictionary will create the object (2). The next threads, will recover the same object (2).
- if the thread is trying to read the data, it will use the object (2) `GetData` method, that will lock until there is data available (in fact, it could read null data, and trigger the `StoreData` and call recursively `GetData` to warranty the creation of data).
  *if the thread is trying to write the data, it will user the object (2) `StoreData` method that will create the lock, and free it when it's written

To do a good implementation you'd need to receive a function that returns the data, so that the creation of the data is also protected by the lock, i.e. use a method like this, instead of `StoreData`:

```
public void CreateStoreData(Func<object> methodThatCreatesData)
{
    // - If there is a lock return inmediately: 
    //   someone is already writing the data
    // - If there is no lock, create the lock, call methodThatCreatesData,
    //   write the data, and release the lock
}
```

Your code then would have to do this:

```
DataCreator dc = new DataCreator(); // prepare the class that generates the data
var userData = UsersData.GetOrAdd(...) // get the dictionary entry for the user
userData.CreateStoreData(dc.DataCreatorMethod);
```

Locking is not a simple task to achieve, and a very, very important thing to do is warranty that any established lock is always release. You can use the try-finally pattern to do so.

Comment: I have provided an example which - I hope - points the situation. Ajax-calls from browser-perspective are no problem.

Comment: Thanks for detailed information. I feared that ... ;) Are the events session-start and session-end are safe concerning they are always triggered? (only used if in-proc I know)